# How to get the date of the next Sunday?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.net get the next tuesday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346119/asp-net-get-the-next-tuesday)

Given a day of the month, how can I get the next sunday from that day?

So if I pass in Tuesday September 13th 2011, it will return Sept. 18th.

Comment: Read the `DayOfWeek` property. Work out how many days before Sunday this is. Call `AddDays` passing that number.

Comment: Is it a homework exercise? If so, tag the question with `homework` tag

Comment: what's wrong if I just have a loop, and increment the day and check if it is the desired day?  break if it is.

Comment: It's just a bit messy if you can do it in one line. I think the nicest solution is like Thomas'; stick the code in an extension method so it will read well, e.g. `var nextSunday = date.Next(DayOfWeek.Sunday);`

Comment: date.AddDays( (TargetDayOfWeek - DayOfWeek) % 7 )

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I use this extension method:

```
public static DateTime Next(this DateTime from, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    int start = (int)from.DayOfWeek;
    int target = (int)dayOfWeek;
    if (target <= start)
        target += 7;
    return from.AddDays(target - start);
}
```

Comment: Isn't using the underlying values of an Enum dangerous?

Comment: +1 for making it an extension method

Comment: @Spencer K: It depends, in case of days of week, I'd be very surprised that it would change in the near (or even far) future ;-)

Comment: I've done quite the same but whiled until the day is met in order to use the enum itself for comparing the days. Another thing to note is that this would not return the Day which is typically starting at 00:00:00. It's the instances same time on that day.

Comment: And call it like so:
Next(DateTime.Now, DayOfWeek.Sunday);

Comment: If you need the Date at 00::00 hours, just add `.Date` to the return, i.e. `return from.AddDays(target - start).Date;`

Answer (score 35):

`date.AddDays(7 - (int)date.DayOfWeek)` should do it I think.

`date.DayOfWeek` will return an enum value that represents the day (where 0 is Sunday).

Comment: I made a small modification on it worked fine for me. DateTime.Today.AddDays(7 - (int)DayOfWeek.Saturday).ToShortDateString()

Comment: Careful dvdnhm, that just adds 1 day to today's date.

Comment: thanks for concern, it worked out fine for my purpose and using it in the project..

Answer (score 11):

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
var nextSunday = date.AddDays(7 - (int) date.DayOfWeek);
```

If you need nearest sunday, code little bit different (as if you're on sunday, nearest sunday is today):

```
var nearestSunday = date.AddDays(7 - date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? 7 : date.DayOfWeek);
```

Comment: Note that this answer finds the `date` of the `Sunday` of the `current week`. If the 7 is exchanged with the `(int) day` of another day of the week, it does not necessarily find the date of the `next` (e.g. wednesday) day. As it returns the date of the day in the current week, it may return a day in the past (but in the current week).

Answer (score 4):

```
/// <summary>
/// Finds the next date whose day of the week equals the specified day of the week.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="startDate">
/// The date to begin the search.
/// </param>
/// <param name="desiredDay">
/// The desired day of the week whose date will be returneed.
/// </param>
/// <returns>
/// The returned date is on the given day of this week.
/// If the given day is before given date, the date for the
/// following week's desired day is returned.
/// </returns>
public static DateTime GetNextDateForDay( DateTime startDate, DayOfWeek desiredDay )
{
    // (There has to be a better way to do this, perhaps mathematically.)
    // Traverse this week
    DateTime nextDate = startDate;
    while( nextDate.DayOfWeek != desiredDay )
        nextDate = nextDate.AddDays( 1D );

    return nextDate;
}
```

Source:

http://angstrey.com/index.php/2009/04/25/finding-the-next-date-for-day-of-week/

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code:

```
int dayOfWeek = (int) DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
DateTime nextSunday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7 - dayOfWeek).Date;
```

Get first the numerical value of the day of the week, in your example: Tuesday = 2

Then subtract it from Sunday, 7 -2 = 5 days to be added to get the next Sunday date. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt=dateTime;
do {
  dt=dt.AddDays(1);
} while(dt.DayOfWeek!= DayOfWeek.Sunday);
// 'dt' is now the next Sunday
```

Your question isn't clear whether the same date is returned if the date is already a Sunday; I assume no, but change the above to a `while` loop if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Example using recursion

```
    private static DateTime GetNextSunday(DateTime dt)
    {
        var tomorrow = dt.AddDays(1);
        if (tomorrow.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            GetNextSunday(tomorrow);
        }

        return tomorrow;
    }
```

Comment: Care to comment downvoter? I hate when people do that...

Comment: I would hate that too! Nevertheless, I think this would not work out well. As mentioned, DateTime instances are immutable and you don't even use the return value of your method. Another thing to mention: It's really nice to put this kind of functionality into extension methods, at least for my taste.