# I want to get coming saturday date and display it on the label using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, weekend, display

I want to get coming saturday date and display it on the label using asp.net c#.
using server date time or Ajax calander extender datetime,.
But every week it will be changed to next saturday day,after the saturday end.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611402/how-to-get-the-date-of-the-next-sunday.

Comment: DateTime.AddDays(1) while DayOfWeek != Saturday will also work, but might be a littlebit slower I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
int datediff = today.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Saturday;
DateTime Saturday = today.AddDays(-datediff);
lblSaturday.Text = Saturday.ToString();
```

Comment: working fine ...thanks

Answer (score 0):

With NodaTime, you can do this:

```
var zone = NodaTime.TimeZones.BclDateTimeZone.ForSystemDefault();
LocalDateTime systemTime = SystemClock.Instance.Now.InZone(zone).LocalDateTime;
var nextSaturday = systemTime.Next(IsoDayOfWeek.Saturday);
```