# Generate list of dates of the following work week

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to generate a list of dates based on the following condition:

- If today is Wednesday and after 6:00PM **OR** it is after Wednesday, then generate the next work week.
- Else generate the current work week.

Work week being defined as Monday-Friday.

So far from googling and pulling two answers from here, I have this extension which gives me the next occurring specified day based on the current day:

```
public static DateTime Next(this DateTime dt, DayOfWeek startoOfWeek)
{
    var start = (int)dt.DayOfWeek;
    var target = (int)startoOfWeek;
    if (target <= start)
    {
        target += 7;
    }
     return dt.AddDays(target - start);
}
```

Pulled from: [How to get the date of the next Sunday?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611402/how-to-get-the-date-of-the-next-sunday)

And I also have the following work days as:

```
var daysOfWeek = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek))
            .OfType<DayOfWeek>()
            .Skip(1)
            .TakeWhile(day => day != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            .ToList();
```

I proceed to test it such:

```
foreach (var day in daysOfWeek)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Next(day).Date.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
}
```

Since today is Sunday 4/24/16, I get the correct output for the next week:

```
> 4/25/2016 0:00:00
> 4/26/2016 0:00:00
> 4/27/2016 0:00:00
> 4/28/2016 0:00:00
> 4/29/2016 0:00:00
```

But if today were say Wednesday 4/27/16, then I get:

```
> 5/2/2016 0:00:00
> 5/3/2016 0:00:00
> 5/4/2016 0:00:00
> 4/28/2016 0:00:00
> 4/29/2016 0:00:00
```

---

I'm getting closer, but I'm wondering if there is an easier way than what I've done already or if there's an answer out there already.

Comment: You do not seem to be taking into account the time component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might seem like overkill, but I'd break it into small functions. First, for any date, given a day of the week, what is the previous instance of that weekday, including the current date? (Translation - given a date, what is the date of the previous Monday, including that date if it is a Monday?)

Then, for any given date and number of days, what is the range of dates?

```
public static class DateFunctions
{
    public static DateTime GetPreviousInstanceOfWeekDay(DateTime forDate, 
        DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
    {
        return forDate.DayOfWeek >= dayOfWeek 
            ? forDate.AddDays(dayOfWeek - forDate.DayOfWeek).Date 
            : forDate.AddDays(-(7-(dayOfWeek - forDate.DayOfWeek))).Date;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDateRange(DateTime startDate, int length)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, length - 1).Select(x => startDate.Date.AddDays(x));
    }
}
```

The main reason is that this is the sort of thing I don't expect to get right on the first try, and the easiest way to verify it is with a few unit tests.

```
[TestMethod]
public void ReturnsPreviousMondayForGivenThursday()
{
    var monday = DateFunctions.GetPreviousInstanceOfWeekDay(DateTime.Parse("4/21/2016"), 
        DayOfWeek.Monday);
    Assert.AreEqual(DateTime.Parse("4/18/2016"), monday);
}

[TestMethod]
public void ReturnsPreviousSaturdayForGivenSunday()
{
    var saturday = DateFunctions.GetPreviousInstanceOfWeekDay(DateTime.Parse("4/17/2016"), 
        DayOfWeek.Saturday);
    Assert.AreEqual(DateTime.Parse("4/16/2016"), saturday);
}

[TestMethod]
public void ReturnsSundayForGivenSunday()
{
    var sunday = DateFunctions.GetPreviousInstanceOfWeekDay(DateTime.Parse("4/24/2016"), 
        DayOfWeek.Sunday);
    Assert.AreEqual(DateTime.Parse("4/24/2016"), sunday);
}
```

That also keeps the Wednesday/6PM check separate from all the rest. This function just combines the other functions, and the only new thing it introduces is logic to check whether it should return five days starting with the previous Monday or with next Monday. (I might even put that in a separate function. A few extra lines of code and a unit test or two are great for peace of mind.)

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetWeekDaysForCurrentOrNextWeek(DateTime forDate)
{
    //Badly named variable. It's late.
    var getStartForWeek = forDate.AddHours(6).DayOfWeek > DayOfWeek.Wednesday
        ? forDate.AddDays(7) : forDate;
    return
        DateFunctions.GetDateRange(
        GetPreviousInstanceOfWeekDay(getStartForWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday), 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
public static DateTime GetStartOfWorkWeek(this DateTime now)
{
    var monday = now.AddDays(1 - (int)now.DayOfWeek).Date;
    if (now.Subtract(monday).TotalHours >= 66.0)
    // 66.0 hours from Midnight Mon to 6pm Wed
    {
        monday = monday.AddDays(7.0);
    }
    return monday;
}
```

If I run this code:

```
var now1 = new DateTime(2016, 4, 27, 17, 59, 0);
var now2 = new DateTime(2016, 4, 27, 18, 0, 0);

var monday1 = now1.GetStartOfWorkWeek();
var monday2 = now2.GetStartOfWorkWeek();
```

...I get these values:

```
now1
2016/04/27 17:59 Wednesday 

monday1
2016/04/25 00:00 Monday 

now2
2016/04/27 18:00 Wednesday 

monday2
2016/05/02 00:00 Monday
```