# How to find the upcoming week day?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

How to set up Bootstrap datepicker `endDate` to next week's Monday, so every time you open calendar no matter what day of the week is today, it should set up the `endDate` to next coming Monday and all dates should be disabled after that day?

I was trying to use endDate: "+1w" but it disables after 7days.

```js
$(".date-picker").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: "01/01/2014",
    endDate: "+1w",
    format: "dd M yyyy"
});
```

Comment: I got solved my problem, so if anyone is interested check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> next coming Monday

You're question is kind of interesting one.  So I was trying to work out but I was not able to sort out a simple logic.  Mean while I came across a similar question in C# 
[**"Datetime - Get next tuesday"**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6346119/1671639)

Here @Jon Skeet had already sorted a simple logic for finding out the next week day.

```
//consider date as April 1, 2014 (TUESDAY)
var daysUntilMonday = (1 - date.getDay() + 7) % 7;
```

---

**Explanation:**

> Here 1 (represents the MONDAY due to days are considered in an array)
>
> // The (... + 7) % 7 ensures we end up with a value in the range [0,
>   6] (As Jon Quoted)

---

Now just add those days and set it back to the date like

```
date.setDate(date.getDate() + daysUntilMonday );
```

### **Complete code:**

```
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      startDate: "01/04/2014",
      endDate: nextMonday("01/04/2014"),
      format: "dd M yyyy"
  });

  function nextMonday(theDate) {
      var dat = theDate.split("/");
      var date = new Date(dat[2], (+dat[1]) - 1, dat[0]);
      var daysUntilMonday = (1 - date.getDay() + 7) % 7;
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + daysUntilMonday);
      return date;
  }
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vtzSd/22/)

**FYI:** 
 what happen if the date is already MONDAY?  Check it..

Comment: In my case if current day is a Monday then next week Monday should be disabled, though thanks for great answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem on my own:

```
var current_day = new Date();
    if(current_day.getDay() == 0){
        $(".date-picker").datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: "01/01/2014",
            endDate: "+0d",
            format:    "dd M yyyy"
        });
    }else if(current_day.getDay() == 1){
        $(".date-picker").datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: "01/01/2014",
            endDate: "+6d",
            format:    "dd M yyyy"
        });
    }else if(current_day.getDay() == 2){
        $(".date-picker").datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: "01/01/2014",
            endDate: "+5d",
            format:    "dd M yyyy"
        });
    }else if(current_day.getDay() == 3){
        $(".date-picker").datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: "01/01/2014",
            endDate: "+4d",
            format:    "dd M yyyy"
        });
    }else if(current_day.getDay() == 4){
        $(".date-picker").datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: "01/01/2014",
            endDate: "+3d",
            format:    "dd M yyyy"
        });
    }else if(current_day.getDay() == 5){
        $(".date-picker").datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: "01/01/2014",
            endDate: "+2d",
            format:    "dd M yyyy"
        });
    }else{
        $(".date-picker").datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: "01/01/2014",
            endDate: "+1d",
            format:    "dd M yyyy"
        });
    }
```