# Determine most recent and next Payday (alternating Fridays)

Tags: c#, datetime

I am very close to getting this to work and hope someone here can help push the ball over the top of the hill.  In C#, I need to get the most recent Payday and the next Payday from today's date (and will eventually expand this to find any pay date in the company's history). Payday occurs every other Friday.  I am using a baseline date from history to find my pay dates.

My assumption (please correct if I am wrong) is that I should always be able to divide my pay date by 14.  If I cannot, then I must be on a non-pay week.

Here is what I have done thus far:

```
public DateTime GetNextPayDay()
{
    DateTime myNow = DateTime.Now;
    string myDay = myNow.DayOfWeek.ToString();
    while (myDay != "Friday")
    {
        myNow = myNow.AddDays(1);
        myDay = myNow.DayOfWeek.ToString();
    }
    DateTime mySeedDate = DateTime.Parse("01/02/1970");
    TimeSpan myTimeSpan = myNow.Subtract(mySeedDate);
    int myDaysDifference = myTimeSpan.Days;
    if (myDaysDifference % 14 == 0) // Problem is here
    {
        myNow = myNow.AddDays(7);
    }

    return myNow;
}

public DateTime GetLastPayDay()
{
    DateTime myNow = DateTime.Now;
    string myDay = myNow.DayOfWeek.ToString();
    while (myDay != "Friday")
    {
        myNow = myNow.AddDays(-1);
        myDay = myNow.DayOfWeek.ToString();
    }

    DateTime mySeedDate = DateTime.Parse("01/02/1970");
    TimeSpan myTimeSpan = myNow.Subtract(mySeedDate);
    int myDaysDifference = myTimeSpan.Days;
    if (myDaysDifference % 14 == 0) // Problem is here
    {
        myNow = myNow.AddDays(-7);
    }

    return myNow;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with what you have so far, exactly?

Comment: You might also consider refactoring your code a bit based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6346190/2589202)

Comment: eddie_cat - Quick reply man!!  And I apologize, I did not make clear what the issue is.  I never get inside the "if" where the problem is.  When I debug through it, my value of myDaysDifference % 14 is always 7. So, the == 0 never evaluates to true.  I believe I just don't properly understand the % operator.  Is there a better approach?

Comment: I think your issue is the `if (myDaysDifference % 14 == 0)` should be a **not** equal - `if (myDaysDifference % 14 != 0)` in both methods.

Comment: Oh good grief!!!  petelids, you are ABSOLUTELY correct.  I feel really dumb right now.  Sometimes we bang our heads over and over on the wall and end up with no answers and a bruised forehead.  Thanks for knocking on my head there a bit!  It is working now.

Comment: You're welcome, we've all been there! :). I've added it as an answer for completeness.

Comment: Why do you make `myDay` a string? Wouldent it be better to do `DayOfWeek myDay = myNow.DayOfWeek; if(myDay == DayOfWeek.Friday)`

Comment: Scott, fair question.  I do that sort of thing a lot so I can debug through the code and see specific values at a given point in time.  I'm not a polished coder by any stretch.  I just try to get things to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is the

```
if (myDaysDifference % 14 == 0)
```

should be a not equal

```
if (myDaysDifference % 14 != 0)
```

in both methods.

Your logic is currently finding the previous Friday from now and then seeing if the difference between that and the first date is divisible by 14 and if so you are adding 7 days to it. This is incorrect as if the gap is divisible by 14 then `myDay` must be a payday. You only want to add 7 if `myDaysDifference` **doesn't** divide exactly by 14 as this would mean you have a Friday that isn't a pay day.