# Getting an integer for the date when the input is a string

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I'm struggling to understand how to get the numbered day (of the month) that corresponds to the string that contains the name of that day. For example, let's assume that Monday is the first of January. I fill a string with the word "Monday". In creating a cron string, I need to change the "Monday" to a "1".

Simply using "Monday" is not an option, since the particular string I am creating specifies *next* Monday (and only next Monday) as the target date.

I can see how to do a comparison with the MSDN article that concerns `DateTime.DayOfWeek`, however I am very unsure how to go about getting the integer that corresponds to the date of next Monday.

*PS - I'm horrifically aware that this is terrible formatting, but for the life of me I don't know how to word it better. You're welcome to have a go.*

Comment: So you want to find date of next Monday starting from today, right? What if it is Monday today, do we use today's date or do we find the next one?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Well, in British English saying "This Monday" tends to always imply the next Monday, regardless of whether it is Monday today. So, in answer to your question, Yes. I want to find the date of next Monday; And yes, we find the next date if Monday is today.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6346190/1803777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to calculate next Monday, it seems that the code has already been listed on StackOverflow (e.g. [Datetime - Get next tuesday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346119/datetime-get-next-tuesday)).  Converting a day string to the `DayOfWeek` enumeration should be fairly trivial if you are only supporting English (just use something like `Enum.Parse()`).  Otherwise, you can take into account the current culture as listed in @Patrick Hofman's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I use this code to make an ordered array of days of the week. (Found something similar myself, not sure where). It takes the days of the week and orders them according to the regional settings.

You can iterate over the `dayNamesShifted` to compare the name of the day and return it's index.

```
int firstDayOfWeek = (int)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
string[] dayNamesShifted = Shift(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames, firstDayOfWeek);
```

Where `Shift` is:

```
private static T[] Shift<T>(T[] array, int positions)
{
    T[] copy = new T[array.Length];
    Array.Copy(array, 0, copy, array.Length - positions, positions);
    Array.Copy(array, positions, copy, 0, array.Length - positions);
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: This is... complicated. I'm not sure I need to change them either, considering that Sunday is always the first day of the week where Quartz.NET is concerned. Besides, won't this give me a number from 1 to 7, as opposed to the date of the actual day?

Comment: That's true. Wasn't that your question? Guess I misunderstood then. Can you clarify?

Comment: If this isn't the answer you were looking for, at least this can help you to determine where you are in the week and get to know how many days you need to add.

Comment: Kinda. I could technically use an integer from 1 to 7, but then it would run every week (or at least every week of that month) unless I deleted the cron after it executed. That would be a bit difficult to implement considering the logs rely on the cron remaining in the directory. I will, however, use this array for the recurring jobs, and for that I appreciate it.

Comment: @Wolfish: Okay. I will keep it then. Thanks for your reply.