# Calculate 14 days sequence order

Tags: c#

Can anyone please help me, how do I calculate fortnightly (14 days) logic using C#?, for a example 14 days start following sequence order on February

- Monday start date 8 Feb (next 22 Feb, 7 March, 21 March etc..)
- Thursday start date 11 February (next 25 Feb, 10 March, 24 March etc..)
- Friday start date 12 February (next 26 Feb, 11 March, 25 March etc..)

My logic is not working for the 14 days day display, because 15 February will come 14 days add, it’ll display “First14days” date 29 February 2016, it is a wrong.

This is C# logic

```html
Day.Days value are Monday, Thursday, Friday etc..
foreach (var Day in day)
{ 
    Example Day.Days = Monday
    Int 14days = (((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), Day.Days) - (int)today.DayOfWeek + 14) % 7);
    DateTime   First14days = today.AddDays(14days);                                    
}
```

My output should be

[image: My output should be]

Comment: Why should the fortnight after the 15th not be the 29th?

Comment: some fortnight  start 15 next 29 etc..

Comment: I see no problem in just adding 14 days to 15.02 or 29.02

Comment: 2016 is a leap year and as such 15th Feb + 14 days is 29th Feb. I can't see anything wrong.

Comment: I have replied this issue name @d4Rk please refer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's you all-in-one solution:

```
// determine the date of next given weekday
DateTime date = GetNextWeekday(DateTime.Today, DayOfWeek.Tuesday); 

// create a list and add the start date (if you want)
List<DateTime> fortnights = new List<DateTime>() { date };

// add as many "fortnights" as you like (e.g. 5)
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
    date = date.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(14));
    fortnights.Add(date);
}

// use your list (here: just for printing the list in a console app)
foreach (DateTime d in fortnights) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(d.ToLongDateString());
}
```

Method to get the next weekday, from: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6346190/2019384

```
public static DateTime GetNextWeekday(DateTime start, DayOfWeek day)
{
    // The (... + 7) % 7 ensures we end up with a value in the range [0, 6]
    int daysToAdd = ((int) day - (int) start.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
    return start.AddDays(daysToAdd);
}
```

Comment: Hello d4Rk,  your logic top line in your code, DateTime.Today, DayOfWeek.Monday it'll display Feb 15, Feb 29, March 14 etc..  This my requirment is in advance six date should display following sequence Feb 22, March 7, March 21 etc.. Also that sequence run forever, in advance 6 date will display. (it should never come Feb 15, Feb 29, March 14 etc..). My fortnights calendar date start (always in advance) Feb 22 Monday, Feb 25 Thursday and Feb 26 Firday. What do I have to change your code?

Comment: Just change the "start" date to whatever you want.. e.g. `DateTime date = GetNextWeekday(new DateTime(2016, 2, 22), DayOfWeek.Monday); `

Answer (score 8):

Simply add `TimeSpan.FromDays(14)` to any date to get a fortnight further on

```
 DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
 TimeSpan fortnight = TimeSpan.FromDays(14);

 for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
 {
     startDate += fortnight;
     Console.WriteLine($"Date for fortnight {i}: {startDate:D}");
 }
```

Comment: Hello Übercoder , Can you please explain for me Time Span is add start date?

Comment: `DateTime newdate = date.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(14));`

Comment: Hello  d4Rk, Yours logic always adding 14 days. my question is I want keep all  6 date list in advance, (14 days display). My date list are same 14 date logic forever (see my out put image) sequence order. It's never come Feb 15 and 29. How can I start first date 22 Feb? Do I need hard code first date?

Comment: `date.Add()` gives you a new DateTime instance each time, so it's up to you, what you do with them (e.g. add them in a list).

Comment: DateTime newdate = date.AddDays(14); - this code is shorter than to add TimeSpan

Comment: Hello Übercoder, This my requirement,  in advance six date should display following sequence Feb 22, March 7, March 21 etc.. Also that sequence run forever, in advance 6 date will display. (it should never come Feb 15, Feb 29, March 14 etc..). My fortnights calendar date start (always in advance) Feb 22 Monday, Feb 25 Thursday and Feb 26 Friday.   How do I start with my requirement because if I use DateTime.Now, it'll come other unnecessary fortnight date.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correct your question this code will be working for you.

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
DateTime anotherTime = DateTime.Now;
var allTimes = new HashSet<DateTime>();

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    anotherTime = time.AddDays(14);
    time = anotherTime;
    Console.WriteLine(anotherTime.ToLongDateString());
    allTimes.Add(time);
}

// or with your example is possible to like this code.
foreach (var Day in day)
{
    anotherTime = Day.AddDays(14);
    time = anotherTime;
    Console.WriteLine(anotherTime.ToLongDateString());
    allTimes.Add(time);
}
```

First create two DataTime objects. then foreach few times, and in for loop statement set `anotherTime = time.AddDays(14)` after that set `time = anotherTime`.

```
//Output: 
//Saturday, February 27, 2016
//Saturday, March 12, 2016
//Saturday, March 26, 2016
//Saturday, April 09, 2016
//Saturday, April 23, 2016
//Saturday, May 07, 2016
```

**EDIT:**

I create and HashSet where you can save all you DateTime who you make it.

Comment: Hello evelikov92 , my logic day will come Example Day.Days = Monday. How do identify using system date, first date to add 14 days. example if day 15 Feb need to add 7 days to my out put. How do I handle this issue your C# code?

Comment: Thank you for you update code. I have added details please refer @d4Rk, my comments.