# 14 days(fortnightly) logic in advance and sequence order

Tags: c#

Can anyone please help me. What I need to C# logic for the display in advance and sequence order six date list on Monday. In advance date list should change after 12.00PM. For example on Monday 28 March, date will display same day(28 March) till 12.00pm. After 12.01 pm, first date start from 11 April 2016. Also same sequence(attached screen). It is never display 4th April, 18th April etc.. (sequence order )..

This is my effort C# code, it's only display single date list.

```html
  public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           DateTime time = new DateTime(2016, 3, 25);
            var breaks = DateTime.Today.AddHours(12D);
           if (breaks>=DateTime.Now)
          {
                                 
           
          }
          else if (time<DateTime.Now)
          {


          }
           
           DateTime anotherTime = DateTime.Now;
            var allTimes = new HashSet<DateTime>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                anotherTime = time.AddDays(14);
                time = anotherTime;
                Console.WriteLine(anotherTime.ToLongDateString());
                allTimes.Add(time);
            }


    }
    }
```

This is my final out put in advance six date list

[image]

Comment: That is an oddly worded question...

Comment: So what is wrong with what you have?

Comment: My C# code will display only  2016, 3, 14 Monday date lists. What I need to display Monday to Friday(in advance)

Comment: You already asked this same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35377602/calculate-14-days-sequence-order and even got an answer.  If you cannot state your question clearly in sentence form or pseudo code, you will not have much luck writing it in code. On the other hand, if you can clearly state your algorithm (like describing to a friend), then the code should be a natural extension of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
            if ((today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday) && (today > new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, 12, 0, 0)))
            {
                today.AddDays(1);
            }
            int offsetToMonday = 7 - (((int)today.DayOfWeek - 1) % 7);
            DateTime nextMonday = today.AddDays(offsetToMonday);
            DateTime startDate = (nextMonday.DayOfYear / 7 % 2) == 0 ? nextMonday : nextMonday.AddDays(7);
            DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(83);
            List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();

            for (DateTime date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
            {
                dates.Add(date);
            }

            var groupedDays = dates.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Subtract(startDate).Days % 14)
                .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
                .Where(x => x.Key == 0);

            foreach (var group in groupedDays)
            {
                foreach (DateTime day in group)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(day.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"));
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. The issue was , if I add DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2016, 3, 14);, it'll display date 14,15,16,17,18, (display date should be grate than system date). Your  code only weekly. I need only 14 days logic.

Comment: Also, date lists should be only, in advance 6 date lists will display always. For example Monday (March 21, April 4, April 18, May 2, May 16 and May 30 )

Comment: Changed Grouping to be two weeks by using DayOfYear

Comment: Found better way of grouping and getting 6 results.  I'm using MOD 14 of the difference between the date and the start date.

Comment: one issue, if you put startDate = DateTime.Now next Monday(28) will display  11 April, 25 April etc.. It is wrong order. For example somebody pay Rent 21 March(assume pay in 14 days ), next payment on  4 April, 18 April etc.. Have to be follow same sequence with six in advance date lists.

Comment: The code then works.  Only issue is the start date.  Need algorithm for finding correct start date.  What rules should I follow.  It looks like you want the start date to be a Monday, but which Monday.  Need to use DAyOfYear and Year since each year starts on a different day of the week.  I've written code like this before and there are many examples on Web.  Usually people ask question like this for payroll every two weeks.

Comment: I modified code to fix startDate.  It works for this year but may need modifications to work for every year.

Comment: Do we need hard code value,  DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(83);
Are there any options?

Comment: Made two changes.  Only printing out every other Monday and changed start date if after noon on Monday.

Comment: Hello jdweng, this is exactly what I need. Thanks for your great help

Comment: Hello  jdweng, When I checked your code today, Monday date will display 11 April (today date 16th). The all date should be in advance. The next (14 day Monday should be 25 April). Example after 11 April 12.00pm should display 25 April to on ward six in advance date lists. Could you please tell me how do I modify your code?

Comment: I changed one instruction (offsetToMonday) which was getting a negative number.  Moved parenthesis.  Instead of adding 6 I subtracted 1 (which gives same mod 7 results) so I get 0 to 6 instead of 1 to 7 for the days to Monday.  When the code is run on Monday (the 7) would of created an error moving the results ahead one week.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand what you exactly want. But I have a similar function in my repository.

```
    public static DateTime GetNextDayOfWeek(DateTime _date, DayOfWeek _dayOfWeek)
    {
        DateTime Result;
        int diff = _date.DayOfWeek - _dayOfWeek;
        if (diff == 0 && _date.Hour * 100 + _date.Minute <= 1200)
            return _date;
        if (diff < 0)
        {
            diff += 7;
        }
        Result = _date.AddDays(-1 * diff).Date;
        if (Result <= _date)
            Result = Result.AddDays(7);
        return Result;
    }
```

I added this part for your needs

```
if (diff == 0 && _date.Hour * 100 + _date.Minute <= 1200) return _date;
```

This functions takes a date and a desired day of week and returns the closest next date when the desired day of week will be present.
Since I understand you want 6 packs of these, you can put it in a loop like this:

```
DateTime next;
next=DateTime.Now;
foreach(DayOfWeek dow in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)))
{
    for(var n=0;n<6;n++)
    {
        next=GetNextDayOfWeek(next, dow);
        //do something with your date
    }
}
```

You could add another parameter for how many days you wand advance. Currently it if fixed to 7. In your case you would need 14.

Comment: date start day 14 March Monday, next 14 days should be Monday 28 March(can't be Monday 21 March)

Comment: Just create a date as 14 Mach 2016 and give it as a first parameter to the function. And change the value 7 to 14.

Comment: Can you pls explain to me, this line (diff == 0 && _date.Hour * 100 + _date.Minute <= 1200), 100 and 1200. Thanks

Comment: I used this to simplify the minute and hour thing. You want that the date changes if after 12:01. I multiply the hour by 100 so if 12 i will get 1200. Than I add the minutes, if it will be something like 05 i will have 1200+05=1205. Your desired time limit would be 1200. So if 1205 is bigger than 12000 (which it is) my IF statement would function correctly.