# Why is comparing a DateTime value to a DateTime value considered an invalid cast?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, generic-list, date-comparison

I've got this code to compare two DateTime values:

```
DateTime currentWeek = Convert.ToDateTime(comboBoxWeekToSchedule.SelectedValue);
List<Student> thisWeeksStudents = (List<Student>)studentsList.Where(i => i.WeekOfLastAssignment.Equals(currentWeek));
```

The Student class' most pertinent member to this discussion is:

```
public DateTime WeekOfLastAssignment { get; set; }
```

After this line:

```
DateTime currentWeek = Convert.ToDateTime(comboBoxWeekToSchedule.SelectedValue);
```

...executes, the value of "currentWeek" is "*2/22/2016 12:00:00 AM*"

I am attempting to filter the generic list for the elements whose "WeekOfLastAssignment" element equate to the value of "currentWeek"; these are represented (as seen in the debugger) as "*{8/14/2015 10:52:55 PM}*"

IOW, they seem to have the same format (except for the encasing "{" and "}", which I doubt are the problem).

I can see that there may be no exact matches, since the combobox values always have midnight as their time element. So maybe I will have to perform a "LIKE %"-type of LINQ operation ("Contains" maybe?), but the first problem is getting past this invalid cast.

This is the precise text of the error I get after the attempted assignment to the generic list named "thisWeeksStudents":

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator`1[AYttFMScheduler.Student]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AYttFMScheduler.Student]'.
```

What need I do to rectify this situation?

In case it may be pertinent, *comboBoxWeekToSchedule* is populated with values like so:

```
private void PopulateComboBoxWithSchedulableWeeks()
{
    int WEEKS_TO_OFFER_COUNT = 13;
    List<String> schedulableWeeks = AYttFMConstsAndUtils.GetWeekBeginnings(WEEKS_TO_OFFER_COUNT).ToList();
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = schedulableWeeks;
    comboBoxWeekToSchedule.DataSource = bs;
}

public static List<String> GetWeekBeginnings(int countOfWeeks)
{
    // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346119/datetime-get-next-tuesday
    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    // The (... + 7) % 7 ensures we end up with a value in the range [0, 6]
    int daysUntilMonday = ((int)DayOfWeek.Monday - (int)today.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
    DateTime nextMonday = today.AddDays(daysUntilMonday);

    List<String> mondays = new List<string>();
    // Need all Mondays, even though 1st Monday is BR only
    if (!IsAssemblyOrConventionWeek(nextMonday))
    {
        mondays.Add(nextMonday.ToLongDateString());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < countOfWeeks; i++)
    {
        nextMonday = nextMonday.AddDays(7);
        if (!IsAssemblyOrConventionWeek(nextMonday))
        {
            mondays.Add(nextMonday.ToLongDateString());
        }
    }
    return mondays;
}
```

Comment: is your `studentsList` a `List<Student>` or is it an `object`?

Comment: Perhaps the student-like objects in `studentsList` cannot be cast to `Student`.  What happens if you access a single element of `studentsList` by index and attempt to cast this to a `Student` type?

Comment: As the where clause returns an iterator, you probably should use ToList() as `studentsList.Where(i => i.WeekOfLastAssignment.Equals(currentWeek)).ToList()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the error you're getting is...

> Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator`1[AYttFMScheduler.Student]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AYttFMScheduler.Student]'.

...the problem is not that it can't cast a `DateTime` to a `DateTime`, it's that it can't cast a `WhereListIterator<T>` to a `List<T>`. I think all you need to do is use `ToList()` instead of a cast, like this:

```
List<Student> thisWeeksStudents = studentsList
    .Where(i => i.WeekOfLastAssignment.Equals(currentWeek))
    .ToList();
```

For your problem of the `Equals` statement never being true (due to comparing a date that is always midnight with one that has a variable time), try just getting the `Date` component, like this:

```
.Where(i => i.WeekOfLastAssignment.Date == currentWeek)
```