# Generate cron expression for weekly and repeat every n weeks

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am trying to create weekly cron expression which will execute every week on selected days like Mon,Tue. Along with this I have to implement repeat every functionality with it. So that trigger would be fired after repeat every interval.

eg. I have to execute job every Monday and alternate week in case when interval value is 2.
When interval value is 3 I have to execute this job every Monday after 2 weeks.

This functionality is easily achieved in case of Daily or monthly, but I am not able to find it in case of weekly.
eg. Cron for daily and repeat every interval as 3
    0 0 12 1/3 * ? *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with cron expressions.

Your best bet is to use the `WithCalendarIntervalSchedule()` method to specify the intervals in weeks you want the trigger to happen:

```
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            .StartNow()
            .WithCalendarIntervalSchedule(
                scheduleBuilder => scheduleBuilder.WithIntervalInWeeks(3))
            .Build();
```

Instead of `StartNow()`, you will also have to use `StartAt()`, and find a way to get the date of the next Monday (using for example Jon Skeet answer from this question: [Datetime - Get next tuesday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346119/datetime-get-next-tuesday))

Comment: Can we schedule it for two/multiple days in week, and specify days of week?

Comment: With the solution above, you will have to create two different triggers (one Starting on next Monday, and one on next Wednesday for instance).

Comment: any help for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013626/scheduling-trigger-using-method-triggerbuilder-startatdatetime-datetime-causin will be great.

Answer (score -2):

http://www.cronmaker.com/
This (or any similar) page can help you, for example, if you set it to every 14 days.

Comment: There is no option for weekly unlike in case of Daily Every 1  day(s)