# C# Looking to type in a Year and pull a date that is placed

Tags: c#

So I have a very small code that I am working on as I am new to C#. 
I am looking to have it ask for the year - I.E - 2020 - and Provide the Month and day I have set behind in code. So for example. I am looking to pull - the 2nd Sunday after the 2nd Tuesday of every month. I have a code that does that now, but I have to change my code for each year. Is there a way to just type in the year and get those dates?

I am just unsure how to go about doing this.

```
Console.WriteLine("Insert Year");
string name =  Console.ReadLine();
for (int mth = 1; mth <= 12; mth++)
{
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(2019, mth, 20);
    while (dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        dt = dt.AddDays(1);
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToLongDateString());
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Assuming you typed "2019" in the input, then `DateTime dt = new DateTime(name, mth, 20);` would do the trick, I expect - it's just swapping the hard-coded year for the variable containing the input. Or you might have to convert it to an integer first. But that's the general idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading an integer from user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443827/reading-an-integer-from-user-input)

Answer (score 2):

`name` is a `string` where `DateTime` need a `int` to year input argument (like `2019` is).

Convert `name` to `int` with :

```
string name =  Console.ReadLine();
int year = int.Parse(name);
```

Then you can use `year` in the `DateTime` object creation :

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, mth, 20);
```

Comment: It was so Easy! Thank you so very much!

Comment: @Ngarda for the "the 2nd Sunday after the 2nd Tuesday of every month" stuff, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346119/datetime-get-next-tuesday