# How to use TryParseExact with just a Time and Day of Week

Tags: c#, datetime, system

How would I `TryParseExact` the following time with day of week:
02:31:42Friday

I have a working `TryParseExact` method but when I use this format string it `returns false:
HHmmssdddd`

Method is:

```
public DateTime? HandleStringToDateTimeExactFormat(string x, string format, CultureInfo culture = null, DateTimeStyles style = DateTimeStyles.None)
{
   DateTime? output = null;
   if(culture == null)
   {
     culture= new CultureInfo("en-US");
   }

   if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
       x,
       format,
       culture, 
       style,
       out DateTime parseOutput
     )
    )
    {
       output = parseOutput;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: The goal is to adjust the year and month so that the next Friday is the ultimate date. 

Like so:
var defaultDateTime = new DateTime(2019, 2, 28, 3, 1, 5);
   var sut = new ChatImportBLL();
   //March 1, 2019 is a Friday
   var result = sut.ParseAcceptedDateTimeFormats("02:31:42Friday", defaultDateTime);
   Assert.AreEqual(2019, result.Year);
   Assert.AreEqual(3, result.Month);
   Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Day);
   Assert.AreEqual(2, result.Hour);
   Assert.AreEqual(31, result.Minute);
   Assert.AreEqual(42, result.Second);

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'HH:mm:ssdddd' ? Don't forget about the colon delimiter

Comment: I strip out colons before I send in the datetime.

Comment: It works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lKSsmR

Comment: @JRKincaid dont do that then

Comment: Also without colons : https://dotnetfiddle.net/iKvuWC

Comment: I am targeting 4.5.2. The code writes the text "Nothing"

Comment: Not sure why there is a bug there :) Are you able to recreate it targeting 4.5.2?

Comment: I was able to work around by taking off the day or week part and then figuring out the New Date based on the start date. Basically the goal is to get a date that is the next Saturday at the right time:

int daysUntil = ((int)DayOfWeek.Saturday - (int)startDateTime.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
    DateTime newDate = startDateTime.AddDays(daysUntil);
 new DateTime(newDate.Year, newDate.Month, newDate.Day, currentParsing.Value.Hour, currentParsing.Value.Minute, currentParsing.Value.Second);

Comment: Sort-of duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346119/datetime-get-next-tuesday gives you all sorts of correct code to pick next Tuesday... Indeed not what you wanted :) but close by couple days.

Comment: Yep found that and then said this sucks but worked around it anyways ;)

Comment: You would think Date Parsing would unit tested to heck at Microsoft.