# How can I get the next date from a list of DayOfWeek?

Tags: c#

In my app I have a `DateTime` and a list of `System.DayOfWeek` and I need to get the next date.

For example, for the date  `2021-06-16` (Wednesday)  & a list containing only `DayOfWeek.Monday`, the next date should be `2021-06-21`

Can anyone help here? I think I need to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6346190) to take a sequence of `DayOfWeek` with the following signature

```
public static DateTime GetNextWeekday(DateTime start, IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> days)
```

Comment: What do you want if the given date is a Monday and the specified day is a Monday? Would the result be the given date, or the given date + 7 days?

Comment: What have you tried sofar? Since you can determine the dayofweek for the date you should be able to work out the difference between the current and the desired and end up with a DateTime.AddDays(differenceBetweenWeekDay)

Comment: _"a list of System.DayOfWeek"_ so the result is not a `DateTime` but `IEnumerable<DateTime>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've got a `GetNextWeekday(DateTime, DayOfWeek)` method, you can just use LINQ to apply that to all of your specified days, and find the minimum value:

```cs
public static DateTime GetNextWeekday(DateTime start, IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> days) =>
    days.Select(day => GetNextWeekday(start, day)).Min();
```

That will fail if `days` is empty, but that's entirely reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accept the current date if it falls on the given day of the week:

```
public static DateTime GetNextWeekday(DateTime start, IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> days)
{
    while (days.Contains(start.DayOfWeek) is false)
    {
        start = start.AddDays(1);
    }
    return start;
}
```

Or if you do not

```
public static DateTime GetNextWeekday(DateTime start, IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> days)
{
    do start = start.AddDays(1);
    while (days.Contains(start.DayOfWeek) is false);
    return start;
}
```

Comment: Note that this solution may enumerate `days` multiple times - which may be fine in some situations, but could be bad if it's the result of a query.

Comment: (Additionally, it will loop infinitely if the sequence is empty.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, but passing an unevaluated query to a method that accepts `IEnumerable` is asking for trouble anyway. This is still an `O(n)` solution assuming an in memory collection. Checking for an empty sequence would definitely be needed in production code though..

Comment: I disagree that it's "asking for trouble" - it can often be very useful to be able to do this, and I generally try to ensure that methods like this *do* only evaluate their input once, and I document it. That avoids queries being materialized unnecessarily. (The documentation of it is really important though.)