# getting value from combobox selection

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to populate `ComboBox` with some strings like

```
comboBox1.DataSource = new List<string> { "By title", "by isbn", "by tag"};
```

How can I make use of selection from this `ComboBox` since I don't know what to put as

`comboBox1.DisplayMember` and `comboBox1.ValueMember`?

Comment: It is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610695/c-sharp-binding-generic-liststring-to-combo-box

Answer (score 1):

Just use `SelectedItem` Property:

```
var selectedItem = (comboBox1.SelectedItem ?? "").ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, your item is just a simple string, so, the text = item. But if you have more complex structures, you might need an array of that type and set `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`.

Then, your code should look like:

```
myType mt = (mytype)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
// Do something based on other type properties
```