# Combobox not showing items? winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Can any of you on stackoverflow explain me how come my combobox is not displaying any items. I have a combobox that get values from another so it only shows specific items, in this case the items are seat rows. I have tried to set a breakpoit and see if its null, and its not it gets the right value. But for some reason the combobox dont display the items ? can any of you help me.

Here is the first combobox selectIndex event:

```
private void cbBookedSeatMovDate_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceReferenceMovieRunTime.MovieRunTimeServiceClient movRunService = new ServiceReferenceMovieRunTime.MovieRunTimeServiceClient();

    string _selectedMovName = Convert.ToString(cbBookedSeatMovInfo.SelectedValue);
    string _selectedMovDate = Convert.ToString(cbBookedSeatMovDate.SelectedValue);

    cbBookedSeatMovTime.DataSource = movRunService.GetRunTimeOnMovNameAndDate(_selectedMovName, _selectedMovDate);
    cbBookedSeatMovTime.ValueMember = "id";
    cbBookedSeatMovTime.DisplayMember = "startTime";
}
```

and here is the combobox event thats not working right:

```
private void cbBookedSeatMovTime_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceReferenceMovieRunTime.MovieRunTimeServiceClient movRunService = new ServiceReferenceMovieRunTime.MovieRunTimeServiceClient();
    ServiceReferenceSeats.SeatsServiceClient seatService = new ServiceReferenceSeats.SeatsServiceClient();

    string _selectedMovTime = Convert.ToString(cbBookedSeatMovTime.SelectedValue);
    string _selectedMovName = Convert.ToString(cbBookedSeatMovInfo.SelectedValue);
    string _selectedMovDate = Convert.ToString(cbBookedSeatMovDate.SelectedValue);

    string _runTimeId = Convert.ToString(movRunService.GetRunTimeOnNameDateAndTime(_selectedMovName, _selectedMovDate, _selectedMovTime));



    cbRow1.DataSource = seatService.GetRowsOnRunTime(Convert.ToInt32(_runTimeId.First()));
    cbRow1.ValueMember = "id";
    cbRow1.DisplayMember = "rowId";

}
```

Here is the LINQ query:

```
public List<TheaterSeat> GetRowsOnRunTime(int RunTime)
{
    var queryResult = (from x in db.TheaterSeats
                        where x.runTime == RunTime
                        select x);
    return queryResult.ToList();
}
```

Hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: You set a breakpoint to see if what is null and get the right value? And if you place the seatService.GetRows on a separate assignment, it really have all your correct values and your properties are really `id` and `rowId` ? (Because if you followed C# conventions it should be `Id` and `RowId` instead, you have to watch out for that)

Comment: yes i have tried with a breakpoint when the event fires. And i can see that the "_runTimeId" gets a value wich is. id and the id is 13. And the seatService.GetRowsOnRunTime is suposed to return all the rows on the runTimeId wich in this case is 13. So i can't understand why nothing is displayed ?

Comment: Set the GetRowsOnRunTime value on a different line (so like `var a = seatService.Get[...]`) and check if the values are really returned. And double check your property names.

Comment: When i do this i can see that a gets a value: {CinemabookingWCFApp.TheaterSeat[0]} that means that there are one item right ?

Comment: There's supposed to be a little `+` sign, if you can expand your object and view the values assigned to your properties, then yes. And btw you have your naming convention at the opposite of C#'s one (supposed to be properties name in PascalCase and fields in camelCase). You can try to use a [BindingSource](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1610704/2316200), but normally your code should work. Try to reduce the problem and create the simplest example you can, hardcoding your values and removing all noise. It will be easier to debug like that.

Comment: Yes when i expand it i can see the movie name the time and the date of the movie. Sorry about the naming convention! i will try to mess aruond with it. thanks for the help Pierre!