# Why do I get, "Cannot bind to the new display member." with this code?

Tags: c#, dictionary, combobox, bindingsource

I have this code to assign the values of a Dictionary to a combo box:

```
private void PopulateComboBoxWithSchedulableWeeks()
{
    int WEEKS_TO_OFFER_COUNT = 13;
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    Dictionary<String, DateTime> schedulableWeeks = 
GetWeekBeginningsDict(WEEKS_TO_OFFER_COUNT);
    bs.DataSource = schedulableWeeks;
    comboBoxWeekToSchedule.DataSource = bs;
    comboBoxWeekToSchedule.DisplayMember = "Key";
    comboBoxWeekToSchedule.ValueMember = "Value";
}

public static Dictionary<String, DateTime> GetWeekBeginningsDict(int 
    countOfWeeks)
{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    int daysUntilMonday = ((int)DayOfWeek.Monday - (int)today.DayOfWeek + 7) 
        % 7;
    DateTime nextMonday = today.AddDays(daysUntilMonday);
    Dictionary<String, DateTime> mondays = new Dictionary<String, DateTime>
();
    if (!IsAssemblyOrConventionWeek(nextMonday))
    {
        mondays.Add(nextMonday.ToLongDateString(), nextMonday);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < countOfWeeks; i++)
    {
        nextMonday = nextMonday.AddDays(7);
        if (!IsAssemblyOrConventionWeek(nextMonday))
        {
            mondays.Add(nextMonday.ToLongDateString(), nextMonday);
        }
    }
    return mondays;
}
```

At runtime, I get, "*Cannot bind to the new display member.*" with this code, though, on this line:

```
comboBoxWeekToSchedule.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't bind `ComboBox` to fields.
Try loading the DataSource after you define the DisplayMember and DisplayValue:

```
comboBoxWeekToSchedule.DisplayMember = "Key";
comboBoxWeekToSchedule.ValueMember = "Value";
comboBoxWeekToSchedule.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: That works without an exception being thrown, but what appears in the combobox is simply one entry that says "(Collection)"

Answer (score 0):

Increase the size of your combobox and I bet it says `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary...` but I suspect you know the answer [From This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610695/binding-a-generic-liststring-to-a-combobox). What kind of echo do you live in anyway?

Comment: No, "(Collection)" is all that's there.

Comment: I guess I'll just load the "DisplayMember" value into the comboboxes, and then parse their values as needed.